# Any way to search across 2 indices similar to an inner join?

Tags: nest, elasticsearch

I don't know if this is possible without restructuring my data into a parent/child relationship, but I have 2 Elasticsearch indices, one containing the main data, and another containing bounding cuboid information relating to items in that data.

Items in both sets have matching Ids, so if it was stored in a SQL database it would be a simple matter of using an inner join to locate details in both tables.

Does anyone know how to do something similar in Elasticsearch? I've investigated various ideas and searched for similar questions, but to no avail.

This search demonstrates extracting the relevant bounding cuboid records that I want to cross-reference...

```
var boundingSearch = client.Search<Cuboid>(bc => bc.Index(index + "_bounding_cuboids")
    .Type("Cuboid")
    .Query(
        q =>
            (q.Range(r => r.OnField(c => c.MinX).GreaterOrEquals(_minPoint.X).LowerOrEquals(_maxPoint.X)) ||
             q.Range(r => r.OnField(c => c.MaxX).GreaterOrEquals(_minPoint.X).LowerOrEquals(_maxPoint.X))) &&

            (q.Range(r => r.OnField(c => c.MinY).GreaterOrEquals(_minPoint.Y).LowerOrEquals(_maxPoint.Y)) ||
             q.Range(r => r.OnField(c => c.MaxY).GreaterOrEquals(_minPoint.Y).LowerOrEquals(_maxPoint.Y))) &&

            (q.Range(r => r.OnField(c => c.MinZ).GreaterOrEquals(_minPoint.Z).LowerOrEquals(_maxPoint.Z)) ||
             q.Range(r => r.OnField(c => c.MaxZ).GreaterOrEquals(_minPoint.Z).LowerOrEquals(_maxPoint.Z))))
    .Size(1000));
```

At present the main data is searched using a simple search...

```
search.QueryString(queryText);
```

What I'd like to do is make the bounding search a filter which is ran along with this search (linking using their Id fields), in order to only return data that falls within a given space.

Any guidance gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go is the parent child relationship. If the join is only for ids and your source is stored the you can use the [terms filter lookup](https://www.elastic.co/blog/terms-filter-lookup).

As for a proper join like query an [unresolved PR](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/3278) is there. But I am not sure when it will be released/fixed.